# How can I make SMTP plugin work with multiple languages?

Tags: 8, emails

I'm using the [SMTP Authentication Support plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) for mail from my Drupal 8 server.

Sending mail from a webform works fine as long as the visitor is using the default language, which is English. It does *not* send when using any other language.

The message in the error log is not helpful:

> Error sending e-mail from email@site.com to email@site.com: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

This makes no sense to me. How can it not be connecting, when the same connection information is ok on English?

How can I resolve this? Here's what I've tried to do:

- I've [asked for support on SMTP's issues page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2839554), but have not received any response yet.
- Set the language detection up two different ways: by domain or by URL. Same result on both.
- Tried two different SMTP servers, with the same result on both.
- Tried SSL and standard protocols for SMTP.

Comment: What major version of Drupal are you asking about? (6, 7, 8)

Comment: @LittleCoding - I'm sorry. It's for Drupal 8.

Comment: This was just a temporary bug in the SMTP module, and was fixed a few months after your bug report in the module's issue queue. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2865696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the parameters are not translatable. In my case it has been solved by overriding the values of the port and protocol variables in `settings.php`.

```
$config['smtp.settings']['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['smtp.settings']['smtp_protocol'] = 'tls';
```

Comment: Thank you. This answere saved my day. A must for all multi-language sites with SMTP Auth Support.

Comment: This answer got the problem backwards, and gives bad advice. The problem is that the configuration parameters were defined as *translatable*, meaning that each language needed its own values for these parameters. This was fixed in the module long before this answer was written, by https://www.drupal.org/node/2865696. Overriding the configuration settings in settings.php is not a good idea (it hides the problem for just these parameters, it doesn't solve it for all parameters) and is no longer needed - just use the current version of the SMTP module where this is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I applied this patch
https://www.drupal.org/node/2865696

After that I copied smtp.settings.yml in the language folder, and I launched drush cim.

I don't know if you use cim/cex for configuration management, but in this way I can send email in other languages

Answer (score -1):

Just for someone who is using Drupal 7 to fix the same issue, because this module's Drupal 7 version does not even have that stupid smtp.schema.yml file. For Drupal 7, go to /sites/all/modules/smtp and in that folder, edit the file called smtp.phpmailer.inc. Find out "Sets connection prefix." and change the "public $SMTPSecure    = '';" into "public $SMTPSecure    = 'ssl';". Then remember to clear the cache and reenable the SMTP module.